# how to get to various attributes in the same order in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file of lines and this in turn saves information, speed, timing and type of surfaces for each line. I want to do is sort this information in a np.array in the order shown below where the id is the number of the line.

```
(id)   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

0   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10

1   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

2   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

3   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

4   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

5  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10
```

...
thanks for any response

Comment: Is this input?  What is expected output?

Comment: is input data ...thanks telliott99

Comment: and... what do you expect as output?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the output explicitly (and the input, while we're at it).

Comment: Do the id numbers appear in your file, or you only added them as a visual guide? I guess they appear, because if that's not the case, you just need to use `numpy.loadtxt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your may find [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) useful.

For example, suppose you have a file with these contents:

datafile:

```
(id)   0   1   
0   1 smooth 
1   11  choppy
2   20  turbulent
3   2  smooth
4   5  choppy
5  7   bumpy
```

Then you can load the data into a numpy structured array with

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.loadtxt('datafile',
               dtype=[('id','int'),('speed','float'),('surface','|S20')], 
               skiprows=1)
```

Notice you can skip the first line of the datafile by specifying `skiprows=1`.

Then you can access rows as usual with numeric indices, such as `arr[1]`,
and you can access columns by names, such as `arr['speed']`.

And you can get the speed in the 3rd row with `arr[3]['speed']` or `arr['speed'][3]`.

For more info on structured arrays, see 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you started...

```
data ='''
(id)   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

0   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10

1   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

2   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

3   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

4   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10 

5  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6  t7 t8 t9 t10'''

for line in data.strip().split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        print '*'.join(line.split())
```

output:

```
(id)*0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9
0*t1*t2*t3*t4*t5*t6*t7*t8*t9*t10
1*t1*t2*t3*t4*t5*t6*t7*t8*t9*t10
2*t1*t2*t3*t4*t5*t6*t7*t8*t9*t10
3*t1*t2*t3*t4*t5*t6*t7*t8*t9*t10
4*t1*t2*t3*t4*t5*t6*t7*t8*t9*t10
5*t1*t2*t3*t4*t5*t6*t7*t8*t9*t10
```